# undefined is not a function (evaluating 'this.setstate(

Tags: reactjs, react-native, axios

I'm react Native beginner. I have write a code for fech data from API using "axios" npm package. When I run is running properly but when it is get data it is throw error.

> undefined is not a function (evaluating 'this.setstate(

I suspect it's something wrong with this binding but I can't figure out how to fix it. Please help me to resolved this error.

Below is my code:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {Platform, StyleSheet, Text, View, ListView} from 'react-native';
import axios from 'axios';

export default class App extends Component {

  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      isolate: true,
      movies: []
    }

  }

  componentWillMount(){
    axios.get('https://facebook.github.io/react-native/movies.json')
    .then(function (response){
      var moviesList = new ListView.DataSource({
        rowHasChanged: (r1,r2) => r1 !== r2
      });
      this.setState({
        isolate: false,
        movies: moviesList.cloneWithRows(response.data.movies)
      });
    }).catch(function(error){
alert(error);
    });
  }
  render() {
if(this.state.isolate){
  return (<View>

    <Text>Loading....</Text>
  </View>);
}

    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <ListView 
        dataSource={this.state.movies}
        renderRow={
          (rowData) => <Text> {rowData.title} </Text>
        }
        >
        </ListView>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `then` callback should be an arrow to get lexical this,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use an arrow function as your callback:

```
axios.get('https://facebook.github.io/react-native/movies.json')
    .then(response => {
        // ...
    }
```

For more details, read [How to access the correct `this` inside a callback?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-inside-a-callback) to understand how `this` works.

Answer (score 1):

Your `this` context is not known inside of the `then` from the ajax call.
Either you used arrow functions to pass the context of `this` or you define a variable `var self = this` right before ajax call and use it in the callback like `self.setState...`

```
componentWillMount(){
    axios.get('https://facebook.github.io/react-native/movies.json')
    .then((response) =>{
      var moviesList = new ListView.DataSource({
        rowHasChanged: (r1,r2) => r1 !== r2
      });
      this.setState({
        isolate: false,
        movies: moviesList.cloneWithRows(response.data.movies)
      });
    }).catch(function(error){
alert(error);
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Regarding your error it happens because you are trying to have access to **this** in the wrong context. A solution is to use arrow function to bind the right context to the **this** keyword.
I would also suggest you to fetch data in the componentDidMount lifecycle method so it becomes:

```
componentDidMount() {
  axios.get('https://facebook.github.io/react-native/movies.json')
    .then(response => {
      var moviesList = new ListView.DataSource({
        rowHasChanged: (r1, r2) => r1 !== r2
      });
      this.setState({
        isolate: false,
        movies: moviesList.cloneWithRows(response.data.movies)
      });
    }).catch(function(error) {
      alert(error);
    });
}
```